# R script with cyrillic symbols in Task Scheduler. Encoding issue

Tags: r, windows-task-scheduler

I have an R script that contains cyrillic symbols (as filtering terms) in it. It is saved with *UTF-8* encoding and locale option is set to `Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', "Ukrainian")`. It works perfectly when I run it manually. I want to run this script through the Windows Task scheduler. Generally, it works (and produces resulting dataset with non-distorted symbols), but it does not filter by terms, written in cyrillic.

I was wondering how this issue can be resolved?

The script, actually looks like

```
library(tidyRSS)
library(googlesheets4)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(adapr)
library(devtools)
library(xlsx)
#devtools::install_github("cran/adapr")
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', "Ukrainian")

my_feed1 <- tidyfeed("https://www.vugledar-rada.gov.ua/index.php?format=feed&type=rss")
my_feed2 <- tidyfeed("https://ugledar.info/feed")

to_filter <- rbind.fill(my_feed1, my_feed2)

term <- which(grepl("город", to_filter$item_title) | grepl("город", to_filter$item_description) | grepl("місто", to_filter$item_title) | grepl("місто", to_filter$item_description))

filtered <- to_filter[c(term),]

d <- Sys.Date()
t <- Sys.time()

print("saving to the disk...")
setwd("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Hanna K\\Newsfeed")
write.xlsx(filtered, paste0("check_news__", d, ".xlsx"))
```

Comment: could you post the R-script that the task scheduler launches? i wonder if this has something to do with the way you load you R-scripts. perhaps source with encoding. E.g. source("myscript.R", encoding = "UTF-8") (or whatever encoding that your script works with)

Comment: @Jagge I've added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to guess the exact source of your problem, but i strongly suspect that it has something to do with the encoding.

try to check the encoding in the console and in the task scheduler, by printing

```
options("encoding")
```

if the encodings differ then you can set the encoding at the top of your script with:

```
options(encoding = "myencoding")
```

confirm that the encoding did indeed change with the first command.